# Link existing Automated test results with TFS manual tests

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, tfs, nunit

I would like to know if it's possible to link and change state of TC in TFS Test plan.
In release definitions we add a task with three steps:
 1. Queue job in Jenkins.
 2. Download artifacts.
 3. Publish Test results.

This steps work correctly, however the Test run which is created have TC listed as names of methods (as shown in Visual studio) and if opened doesn't have a link to manual test case.
(The tests are written using Selenium and Nunit and linked - associate automation)

What we are trying to achieve:
 1. Have the tests in Test run have links to manual test (steps).
 2. Set the status of tests to pass/fail inside Test plan.

Would be really grateful for suggestions.

The configuration of Task:

[image: Task view]

Comment: What are you using to run tests now? MsTest? NUnit, xUnit? How is your build pipeline configured?

Comment: @GregBurghardt we are using NUnit. As i mentioned in the steps, we are triggering the Job from build release, then download artifacts and publish them:

Comment: I tagged your question with "nunit" just now. You might get a little more attention from people who search on this tag.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Ok, thanks. I just thought it's more of TFS or Azure question.

Comment: The solution will likely involve both TFS and NUnit. The test executor needs some way to communicate back to TFS.

Comment: @GregBurghardt The "Publish Test results" step in Tasks is actually already doing it. It publishes the results from TestResult.xml and creates a Test run with it. The problem is that the result run doesn't have any association with existing manual test cases in TFS. (even thought the tests are linked using the associate automation function)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to associate automated tests with test cases, add the test cases to the test suite, and run VSTest to make `Select tests using` set to `Test Plan`.

[image]

[image]

The test cases in test run list with test cases name, not methods name.

[image]

If you want to modify the test point, you could refer to [Points - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/points/update?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) API:

`PATCH https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/Suites/{suiteId}/points/{pointIds}?api-version=5.0`

Comment: Hello @Cece Dong - MSFT. As far as i understand it will only work if i we run the tests from TFS? I am basically trying to execute tests from Jenkins and from TFS only to trigger job and get the result file and publish it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see there is a workaround for tests from Jenkins.

Comment: yeah, looks like it. Your solution is great if we want to run tests from TFS, but we won't be moving from Jenkins (too much work to migrate). I think will just write simple API requests for it inside tests framework. Thank you!